# Magento 2 add JS only on specific static page

Tags: layout, cms-pages, magento2.4.0

I have created one static page, I wanna load specific JS only on specific static page, Here my static page name is ship_custom_page
If I have to load specific JS in product page so I am using `catalog_product_view.xml` but how can I load only for specific static page ? and I am using community Magento2.4.0 version so Magento removed update layout field from static page.

My custom cms page url key is `custom-shipping-page`

Here is my code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Cms::js/map-file.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Custom Layout Update` section from `Design` tab in CMS page

- Create `cms_page_view_selectable_custom-shipping-page_AnyLayoutName.xml` at

`<theme_dir>/<Namespace>_<Module>/layout` with your desired content.

for more information refer [Dev docs](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/design/layout-update-place-block.html)

- Select `AnyLayoutName` from drop down for `Custom Layout Update` in Admin for CMS page.

Hope above will help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a selectable layout as explained at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#create-cms-pageproductcategory-specific-selectable-layouts

Selectable layout updates can only be loaded from the global store theme and work only in the single website with single theme configurations. If a specific entity like cms-page/product/category has an individual theme applied in the design configuration tab, the selected theme will have priority over the selected layout update.

If selectable layout doesn't work for you for the above mentioned reason. Then you can try the following:
Create custom page XML layout file within your custom module or theme:
cms_page_view_id_[page-url-key].xml
Example :: cms_page_view_id_home.xml

References::

1. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html
2. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html